# My code in pygame is not working right now

Tags: python, pygame

So I made this script

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)

a = 25
b = 25
pygame.init
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("AppliedShapes")
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
  screen.fill(black)


  pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(320,240),(a),0)
  time.sleep(0.7)
  if a == 250:
      a = a-b
  elif a < 250:
      a = a+b

  pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to make this script make a circle go bigger ten times and them smaller but it is not working. It grows bigger perfectly but it does not work going back. Can you help me?

Comment: try using a variable `increasing = True` and set it to False when a == 250. Then, `if increasing: a += b else: a -= b`

Comment: Could you consider adding a more specific title to the question? This is not related to pygame itself but rather the algorithm you're describing

Comment: I would solve it similar to @Rabbid76. However the answer doesn't indicate what the problem was and it's important for you to understand that. You likely would have been able to fix it had you seen this. Your code you increments `a` by `b` when `a < 250` and in the other case if `a == 250` you subtract `b` instead. That means that `a` will increase until it hits 250 and then will be reduced to 225, at which point it is below 250 so on the next pass it will follow the `< 250` case and be incremented again. So it will oscillate between 250 and 225. A debugging print of `a` would have shown this.

Comment: Also since you are trying to learn pygame I would suggest you use `clock.tick(1.4)` instead of `time.sleep(0.7)` to maintain your frame rate. See docs for [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

Comment: @cnexans sorry for the bad title, I was just in a hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert `b` if `a <= 25` or `a >= 250`:

```py
while True:
  # [...]
  
  a += b
  if a <= 25 or a >= 250:
      b = -b
```

Complet code:

```py
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import * 

red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
a = 25
b = 25
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("AppliedShapes")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (320,240), a, 0)
    time.sleep(0.7)
    pygame.display.update()

    a += b
    if a <= 25 or a >= 250:
        b = -b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pygame 
import time 
from pygame.locals import * 

red = (255,0,0) 
black = (0,0,0)

a = 25
b = 25
pygame.init
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("AppliedShapes")
increasing = True
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
  screen.fill(black)


  pygame.draw.circle(screen,red,(320,240),(a),0)
  time.sleep(0.7)
  if a == 250:
    increasing = False
  if increasing:
    a += b
  else:
    a -= b

  pygame.display.update()
```